# Why does socket.isOutputShutdown() returns false even if the socket is closed?

Tags: java, sockets

The Java Socket API tells me that closing a socket will also close the socket's `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.

Neither the Socket API Javadoc, nor the Input/OutputStream API info defines (I haven't found it yet) exactly what "*shutdown*" means for an `OutputStream` or `InputStream`, but I have been assuming that closing either puts them into a "*shutdown*" state.

However, after I invoke my client socket's `close()` method successfully (invoking `isClosed()` returns `true`), if I then invoke either that socket's `isInputShutdown()` or `isOutputShutdown()` method, the result is a `false`.

I'm confident that neither stream has unread/unsent data buffered at the time the Socket's `close()` is invoked.

I'm assuming that I don't understand what "is shutdown" means for a socket's input/output streams, and/or when shutting down occurs.

Comment: I believe you mean isOutputShutdown ?

Comment: Thank you @Jean-François Savard - I edited the question to change "isInputStreamShutdown" and "isOutputStreamShutdown" to the correct method names in those two places.

Answer (score 3):

Even after invoking *socket.getOutputStream().close()*, the *socket.isOutputShutdown()* call will return false.
Also, if the socket is not even connected yet, the *socket.isOutputShutdown()* will return false.

The invokation of *socket.isOutputShutdown()* **ONLY** returns true, when *socket.shutdownOutput()* has previously been called. 
You are right that the doc is a little misleading in that point.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206605/purpose-of-socket-shutdownoutput), the use of *socket.shutdownOutput()* is explained in more detail. Basically you can use it to create a half closed connection (meaning your end is determined to not send anymore data, but willing to listen for more data from the other end).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Whatever you do, the only way to get `true` after calling `isOutputShutdown` is to call `shutdownOutput` before. No matter the state of the `Socket`. The output really need to be closed directly for the method to return true, not just closed by inheritance.

---

The best way to solve this is to look at the source code ;)

Let start by searching the method isOutputShutdown in `java.net.Socket`:

```
public boolean isOutputShutdown() {
    return shutOut;
}
```

It's simply an accessor, alright then let search for `shutOut`. We will then notice that the value is set to true only when calling the method `shutdownOutput` (which is logical)

```
public void shutdownOutput() throws IOException
{
    if (isClosed())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    if (!isConnected())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is not connected");
    if (isOutputShutdown())
        throw new SocketException("Socket output is already shutdown");
    getImpl().shutdownOutput();
    shutOut = true;
}
```

Notice here that we throw a `SocketException` if the socket is closed which up to now, confirm your thought that closing the `Socket` also close it stream. Now let's have a look at `getImpl` to find what does it reference and check the method `shutdownOutput` from it reference.

```
SocketImpl getImpl() throws SocketException {
    if (!created)
        createImpl(true);
    return impl;
}
```

The javadoc of the method specify that it return the `SocketImpl` attached to this socket. Creating it if necessary but I doubt it is considerable in our debugging. `SocketImpl` is simply an abstract class, and we have to find which implementation really override the `shutdownOutput` method.

Now we are able to find that the implementation is using a factory to get an `instance`

```
factory.createSocketImpl()
```

So let's have a look at `SocketImplFactory`. Well the class is an interface with one line `SocketImpl createSocketImpl();`. Then how is the instance of `SicketImpl` given, where is really defined the method `shutdownOutput` ?

Let's have a look at `AbstractPlainSocketImpl` (default socket creation) which extends our `SocketImpl` it is stated in the javadoc at the top by Mr Steven B. Byrne that this is the default socket implementation. So, I think from here we should be able to get a good idea of what does `shutdownOutput` is really doing.

```
/**
 * Shutdown read-half of the socket connection;
 */
protected void shutdownInput() throws IOException {
  if (fd != null) {
      socketShutdown(SHUT_RD);
      if (socketInputStream != null) {
          socketInputStream.setEOF(true);
      }
      shut_rd = true;
  }
}

/**
 * Shutdown write-half of the socket connection;
 */
protected void shutdownOutput() throws IOException {
  if (fd != null) {
      socketShutdown(SHUT_WR);
      shut_wr = true;
  }
}
```

Interesting, isn't it ? For the sake of our debugging, let consider `fd` is not null in our case and go directly to `socketShutdown`.

> But wait ! What is SHUT_WR ?

Good question, as @EJP stated in comment, they are a long-standing part of the Berkeley Sockets API. They simply specify how to proceed (0 for reading, 1 for writing)

```
public final static int SHUT_RD = 0;
public final static int SHUT_WR = 1;
```

Now back to `socketShutdown`,

```
abstract void socketShutdown(int howto)
    throws IOException;
```

Once again, what a shame, I tought we had it...

So let's go in the class `PlainSocketImpl` which extends `AbstractPlainSocketImpl`.

```
native void socketShutdown(int howto) throws IOException;
```

We can find the sourcecode of `java.net.PlainSocketImpl.c` [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~chegar/6882910/webrev.00/webrev/src/solaris/native/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.c.frames.html). Now let's have a look at the code of our method

```
Java_java_net_PlainSocketImpl_socketShutdown(JNIEnv *env, jobject this,
                                           jint howto)
{

  jobject fdObj = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, this, psi_fdID);
  jint fd;

  /*
   * WARNING: THIS NEEDS LOCKING. ALSO: SHOULD WE CHECK for fd being
   * -1 already?
   */
  if (IS_NULL(fdObj)) {
      JNU_ThrowByName(env, JNU_JAVANETPKG "SocketException",
                      "socket already closed");
      return;
  } else {
      fd = (*env)->GetIntField(env, fdObj, IO_fd_fdID);
  }
  JVM_SocketShutdown(fd, howto);
}
```

Now I think you have a pretty good idea of how the method really proceed to close the stream.

> what "shutdown" means for an OutputStream or InputStream

But why does `isOutputShutdown` return false while `isClosed` return true ?

Well considering the `shutOut` boolean is set to true only at the end of the method `shutdownOutput`

```
public void shutdownOutput() throws IOException
{
    if (isClosed())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    if (!isConnected())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is not connected");
    if (isOutputShutdown())
        throw new SocketException("Socket output is already shutdown");
    getImpl().shutdownOutput();
    shutOut = true;
}
```

that mean that closing the `Socket` by default does not set that boolean to `true`. But even if the method return false, it is actually closed as it can't be opened if the `Socket` the `Stream` is based on is closed.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard (and everyone else) Thank you so much for dissecting the code that creates the behavior.  I wouldn't say this part of the Socket-communication state-machine is implemented well, but I do understand it better now.

Answer (score 1):

`shutdownOutput()` causes a FIN to be sent after any pending data, which the peer will see as end of stream.

*If you have called* `shutdownOutput()`, `isOutputShutdown()` will then return `true.` In all other cases and regardless of the other state of the socket or the connection, it returns false.

Similarly for:

- `shutdownInput()` and `isInputShutdown()`
- `close()` and `isClosed()`
- `connect()` or construct a `new Socket(...)` with arguments, and `isConnected()`.

None of these APIs magically changes state unless your application calls the associated API. The only exception to that is `isBound()`, which can become true if you call `bind()`, or `connect()`, or  construct a `new Socket(...)` with arguments, or obtain one via `ServerSocket.accept().`

***And*** none of them changes state depending on what the *peer* does to the *connection.* Specifically, `isClosed()` doesn't mean the peer closed the connection. It means *you* closed *this socket.*