# SocketException: Sending object through Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am new to Socket programming.I want to send an Object of class Person to the server using Sockets. There is an exception of Server Socket.
 Class person is as follows:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Person implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String id;

    public Person() {}
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Person(String name, String id) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I first run my server . The server code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;    
import java.net.*;
public class Server extends Thread {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream inStream=null;
    ObjectOutputStream outStream=null;

    public void run(){
        try{
            serverSocket=new ServerSocket(2004);
            socket=serverSocket.accept();
            this.outStream=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            outStream.flush();
            this.inStream=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while(true){
                System.out.println("recieving  data");
                Person person=(Person)this.inStream.readObject();
                //queue.put(person);
                System.out.println(person.getName()+"  "+person.getId());
            }

        }
        catch(EOFException e){
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Server().start();
    }
}
```

Then I run my client. Its code is as follows.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Client {
    Socket socket;

    ObjectInputStream inStream=null;
    ObjectOutputStream outStream=null;
    String ip="localhost";  
    boolean connected=false;
    public Client(String ip){
            this.ip=ip;
    }
    public Client(){
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Client().connect();
    }

    public boolean connect(){
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, 2004);
            System.out.println("Client starting");
            this.outStream=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            outStream.flush();
            this.inStream=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String name;
            System.out.println("sending data");
            outStream.writeObject(new Person("faisal ","232323"));

        }catch(EOFException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"EOFException");
            System.out.println("I am inside Connector EOFException"); 
            connected=false;
            //System.out.println("PoolRunner Client side Disconnected");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IOException");
            System.out.println("I am inside Connector IOException");
            System.out.println(e);
            connected=false;
        }

        finally{
            return(connected);
        }
    }

    public ObjectInputStream getObjectInputStream(){
        return this.inStream;
    }
    public ObjectOutputStream getObjectOutputStream(){
        return this.outStream;
    }
    public void disconnect(){
        try{
            this.inStream.close();
            this.outStream.close();
            this.socket.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problem in closing streams or socket");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problem in closing streams or socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Following Exception is thrown at the server side.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace (or at least which line on the server that exception was thrown at)? Also, has the server printed any objects/receiving data/etc.?

Comment: That is probably because the client closes the connection and your server is still trying to read from the input stream.

Comment: actually he never closed the connections...

Comment: @QuakeCore The client program will exit after it writes the object but the server will keep reading because it uses an infinite loop.

Comment: lol i have an answer but no matter what i do i cant post it due to formatting issue

Answer (score 1):

well your code had some flaws in it, such as not closing the connections, misplaced while loops, you know the usual stuff :)

Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server extends Thread {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
    ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;

    public Server() {
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2004);
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                this.outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                outStream.flush();
                this.inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                System.out.println("recieving  data");

                Person person = (Person) this.inStream.readObject();
                // queue.put(person);
                System.out.println(person.getName() + "  " + person.getId());
            }

        }

        catch (EOFException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Server().start();

    }
}
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Client {
    Socket socket;

    ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
    ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;
    String ip = "localhost";
    boolean connected = false;

    public Client(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public Client() {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Client().connect();
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, 2004);
            System.out.println("Client starting");
            this.outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            connected = true;

            String name;
            System.out.println("sending data");
            outStream.writeObject(new Person("faisal ", "232323"));
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "EOFException");
            System.out.println("I am inside Connector EOFException");
            connected = false;
            // System.out.println("PoolRunner Client side Disconnected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IOException");
            System.out.println("I am inside Connector IOException");
            System.out.println(e);
            connected = false;
        }

        finally {
            if (connected) {
                disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObjectOutputStream getObjectOutputStream() {
        return this.outStream;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            this.outStream.close();
            this.socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Problem in closing streams or socket");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Problem in closing streams or socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hahahaha, posting the answer took me more time that figuring  out the answer, Crazy Formatters!

Answer (score 0):

Your client doesn't do anything with the socket after sending the object, it just quits. If you don't close a connection properly before ending the process, the operating system gets confused and will just reset the connection.

You'll need to call shutdownOutput() and close() on the socket.

See also [purpose of socket.shutdownOutput()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206605/purpose-of-socket-shutdownoutput)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right! I have fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

In Client.java, change main to the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Client cl = new Client();
    cl.connect();
    cl.disconnect();
}
```

This makes your client close its connections to the server before closing. This helps prevent the OS from resetting the connection as mentioned by escitalopram